# How to convert a pandas DataFrame into a table in the reportlab module?

Tags: python, pandas, reportlab

I have the DataFrame below:

[image]

The issue is that when I try to make a table out of `summary_debit` which is a `DataFrame`, I will get the following error: `ValueError: <Table@0x2231B045208 unknown rows x unknown cols>... invalid data type`

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import *
from reportlab.lib import colors

colwidths = 50
GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
            [('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.pink),
            ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT')])

t1 = Table(summary_debit)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I built a sample for your DataFrame image, but you can extends that.

After running code I got a proper pdf.

I hope this code help you.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus import *
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Account Name': ['ACCOUNT PAYABLE', 'PAGIBIG LOAN PAYABLE','PREPAID TAX']
            ,'': [-0.1, -0.2,-0.3]}
summary_debit = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

colwidths = 50
GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
            [('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.pink),
            ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT')])

#t1 = Table([summary_debit.iloc[:,1].tolist(),summary_debit.iloc[:,0].tolist()]);
t1 = Table(np.array(summary_debit).tolist());
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("table.pdf", pagesize=letter)
element = []
element.append(t1)
doc.build(element)
```

---

PDF image export

[image: pdf export]

Comment: Dataframe column names won't be displayed. How to display titles in table?

Comment: t1.setStyle(GRID_STYLE) to apply style